# Space after exponent e.g. \unit{cm^{3}/s} command in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

When I use e.g. `\unit{cm^{3}/s}` there is a space between the '3' and the '/'. I can reduce it with `\!` but is there a more 'proper' way of using the `\unit` command to reduce this space?

Comment: The space comes from `\scriptspace` that's always added after an atom with a subscript or superscript. Its default value is 0.5pt. Maybe JW can find a method for removing the `\scriptspace` in those cases.

Comment: @egreg But that's exactly what the reference rendering does too: `$\mathrm{cm}^{3}/\mathrm{s}$`.

Comment: @JosephWright You didn't read chapter 18 of the TeXbook, did you? Particularly the example `$x^2\!/2$` on page 169. `;-)`

Comment: The problem is not only from `\scriptspace`, but also from the very shape of `/`.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I did ;) The 'reference' here is based on the documented semantics of `\si` with 'literal' input. Only `.` and `~` get 'special' treatment, based on the older `SIstyle` package. Everything else goes to math-mode 'as is': I've never wanted to do parsing on literal input.

Comment: @JosephWright Would correcting the space when using the macro input `\si[per-mode=symbol]{\cubic\centi\meter\per\second}` instead of literal one be within the scope of `siunitx`, i.e. a valid feature request?

Comment: @schtandard Yes, I guess (still tricky, but probably doable)

Comment: I created a [feature request](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/364).

Answer (score 2):

Upcoming `siunitx` v3.1 will offer option `per-symbol-script-correction` with a standard setting of `\!` to cover this case. This is automatically inserted where `per-mode` will use a symbol *and* the last entry in the numerator has a superscript power.